# MySQL Case When Statement

Tags: mysql

How do I strip results with null (or zero) results when using GROUP BY and CASE WHEN logic?

a hypothetical example is:

```
SELECT City, 
   SUM(case when name2015 = 'Jane' then income2015 end) income2015_total,
   SUM(case when name2020 = 'Jane' then income2020 end) income2020_total
from finaldata
GROUP BY City
```

with a database of all people. This will return 3 columns, city, total income of all Janes for 2015, and total income for all Janes for 2020. However, it will return a row for all cities even if they have no Janes. These cities will have null results in the last 2 columns. How do I strip these out in the query so I only get rows for cities that contain at least 1 Jane?

Comment: Provide some sample data perhaps on http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: See COALESCE. But really this looks like poor design. You should (almost) never have enumerated columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT City, 
   SUM(CASE WHEN name2015 = 'Jane' THEN income2015 ELSE 0 END) income2015_total,
   SUM(CASE WHEN name2020 = 'Jane' THEN income2020 ELSE 0 END) income2020_total
from finaldata
GROUP BY City   
HAVING income2015_total <> 0 OR income2020_total <> 0
```

I have added `ELSE 0` in the `CASE` expressions, so that `0` instead of `NULL` is returned by `SUM` in case no match is found.

The above will work provided that `income2015` and `income2020` values are always positive numbers.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0f9ae/1)

Comment: @Downvoter Could you please explain the reason for the downvote, so that I can correct my mistake and learn from my errror ?

Comment: Does MySQL actually let you refer to column alias from the `select` clause in the `group by` clause? I wasn't the downvoter though. Another consideration is that the sum might indeed legitimately be zero.

Comment: @shawnt00 [1] Yes, it does let you, see fiddle demo [2] Yes, this is correct, my `HAVING` clause is  buggy. That's why I asked for an explanation!

Comment: @shawnt00 I have to add though that, in case income values are positive, my query is correct.

Comment: Yeah, I should have looked at the demo although I wasn't really at all surprised that MySQL allows that. But it's clearly non-standard and might still have contributed to the down vote.

Comment: Thanks all. What a great community. Despite the limitation of non-zero values, this answer suits me better. It will be easier to develop this query in code and less verbose particularly if the user wants to query by many 'names'.

Answer (score 1):

You need a WHERE clause like that:

```
SELECT City, 
   SUM(case when name2015 = 'Jane' then income2015 end) income2015_total,
   SUM(case when name2020 = 'Jane' then income2020 end) income2020_total
from finaldata
WHERE name2015 = 'Jane' OR name2020 = 'Jane'
GROUP BY City
```

Comment: Actually I hadn't even noticed that there were two columns being compared to 'Jane'. Clearly it's best just to do it in the `where` clause.

Comment: Yeap, your answer was better overall though. But in this specific question mine works too.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT City, 
   SUM(case when name2015 = 'Jane' then income2015 end) income2015_total,
   SUM(case when name2020 = 'Jane' then income2020 end) income2020_total
from finaldata
GROUP BY City
HAVING COUNT(case when 'Jane' in (name2015, name2020) then 1 else null end) > 0
```

It's my personal preference to count non-nulls rather than to sum ones and zeroes. Up to you.

Answer (score 0):

try below-

```
SELECT City, 
   SUM(case when name2015 = 'Jane' then income2015 end) income2015_total,
   SUM(case when name2020 = 'Jane' then income2020 end) income2020_total
from finaldata 
where (name2015='Jane' or name2020='Jane')  
GROUP BY City
```